# Linux Demon Service does not restart app properly

Tags: linux, .net-core, service

I wrote a demon Service for Linux to restart a specific app, when it crashes but it does not do so. Although it seems to run as it should. The APP that crashes sometimes does not really throw an error message i could use, so i figured i did something wrong in creating the service.

i put this service into the /etc/systemd/system/ directory

```
[Unit]
Description=APPThatshouldRestart

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/v1/TopSquadServer/published
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/v2/APPThatshouldRestart
Restart=always
RestartSec=86400

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

is there a better way to make sure it restarts after the Time i put into the service config?

Is there a way to provide more data why the specific app crashes, rather than using Journal?